# While loop initiating when I dont want it to

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm going over the formatting of the while loop and I remain unsure (I'm a beginner- forgive me) of how I can go about fixing this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! I do not want the 'Sorry that's not it' message to pop up when the user asks for a hint- and yet it persists in doing just that.

```
# Word Jumble
#
# The computer picks a random word and then "jumbles" it
# The player has to guess the original word

import random

# create a sequence of words to choose from
WORDS = ("python", "jumble", "easy", "difficult", "answer", "xylophone")
# pick one word randomly from the sequence
word = random.choice(WORDS)

hint = ''

if word == 'python':
    hint = 'snake'
if word == 'jumble':
    hint = 'jumble'
if word == 'easy':
    hint = 'opposite of hard'
if word == 'difficult':
    hint = 'opposite of easy'
if word == 'answer':
    hint = 'question'
if word == 'xylophone':
    hint = 'dingding'
# create a variable to use later to see if the guess is correct
correct = word

# create a jumbled version of the word
jumble =""
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]


count = 0

# start the game
print(
"""
           Welcome to Word Jumble!

   Unscramble the letters to make a word.
(Press the enter key at the prompt to quit.)
"""
)
print("The jumble is:", jumble)

guess = input("\nYour guess: ")
while guess != correct and guess != "":
    print("Sorry, that's not it.")
    count += 1
    hint_input = input('would you like a hint')
    if hint_input == 'y':
        print(hint)
    else:
        guess = input("Your guess: ")

if guess == correct:
    print("That's it!  You guessed it!\n")

print("Thanks for playing.")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Please give us the full stacktrace, so we can see what's wrong with your code

Comment: Sorry- my wording was off. Didn't mean an error. Fixed in the description

Comment: Remove the `else:` since you always wish to get a new guess from the user, regardless of if they've received a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the else: since you always wish to get a new guess from the user, regardless of if they've received a hint.

```
    if hint_input == 'y':
        print(hint)
    guess = input("Your guess: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine - but you are expected to enter a string including the `"` or `'` in the input field. So enter `"jumble"` and not just `jumble` or `"y"` and not just `y`.

(well, there is some strange logic in there, e.g. after giving a hint it asks once more whether you want a hint - jus remove the `else` to get rid of this behaviour) but at least it works...)

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code and ran it.
I changed input to raw_input, which makes input much nicer. 
Removed else: after print(hint) , which should fix your problem. 
Lastly, I've added extra space after "Would you like a hint? "  - makes it  a bit easier to read.

```
# Word Jumble
#
# The computer picks a random word and then "jumbles" it
# The player has to guess the original word

import random

# create a sequence of words to choose from
WORDS = ("python", "jumble", "easy", "difficult", "answer", "xylophone")
# pick one word randomly from the sequence
word = random.choice(WORDS)

hint = ''

if word == 'python':
    hint = 'snake'
if word == 'jumble':
    hint = 'jumble'
if word == 'easy':
    hint = 'opposite of hard'
if word == 'difficult':
    hint = 'opposite of easy'
if word == 'answer':
    hint = 'question'
if word == 'xylophone':
    hint = 'dingding'
# create a variable to use later to see if the guess is correct
correct = word

# create a jumbled version of the word
jumble =""
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]


count = 0

# start the game
print(
"""
           Welcome to Word Jumble!

   Unscramble the letters to make a word.
(Press the enter key at the prompt to quit.)
"""
)
print("The jumble is:", jumble)

guess = raw_input("\nYour guess: ")
while guess != correct and guess != "":
    print("Sorry, that's not it.")
    count += 1
    hint_input = raw_input('would you like a hint? ')
    if hint_input == 'y':
        print(hint)

    guess = raw_input("Your guess: ")

if guess == correct:
    print("That's it!  You guessed it!\n")

print("Thanks for playing.")

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: While I was posting the answer, several people also answered it and commented as well. If raw_input acts differently in Python 3 than in Python 2.7 (which I use), then ignore that part.

Comment: @Zack : You are welcome.  Hope that the answer works fine on your machine.